# Get product version rather than file version

Tags: wix

I'm familiar with getting the file version using `!(bind.FileVersion.{fileID})`, but is there any way to pull the product version instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiX doesn't support that today, just file version and language.

Comment: Hmm. My end goal is really just to get a 3 part version number, but the file version seems to require the revision portion. Any other way to accomplish this short of hardcoding it every update?

Comment: Not in WiX itself today. Sounds like you could do it as part of the build, before building your setup.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Could you elaborate / refer me to an example or tutorial?

Comment: Use MSBuild, like WiX does: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/tools/WixBuild.Version.targets